# How to bind data user control inside listbox WP8

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-phone-8

I have a user control. It has a `TextBlock`. I want to bind Text in it

```
<UserControl x:Class="PhoneApp1.MyUserControl"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <StackPanel Width="200" Height="200" Background="Red">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In `MyUserControls.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", 
            typeof(string), 
            typeof(MyUserControl), 
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

When I bind to `ListBox` it doesn't work correctly

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="mainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:MyUserControl Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="5"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

and MainPage.xaml

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    ObservableCollection<User> list = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        User user = new User("Thanh");
        list.Add(user);
        list.Add(new User("lfjlkgj"));
        DataContext = list;
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public User(string name)
    {
        Text = name;
    }
}
```

How to bind to user controls correctly? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from your `UserControl` Xaml

```xml
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Binding in the control's xaml will correctly bind to the defined dependency properties. You don't need to do anything extra.

If you have name conflicts with other data sources in your user control you can add `ElementName=UserControl` to your binding.

Comment: Thank you I found the way bind data correctly only ElementName=nameofUserControl