# How to bind data user control inside listbox

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to bind user control inside listbox, but it seems I am doing something wrong, Though I followed [How to bind data user control inside listbox WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998578/how-to-bind-data-user-control-inside-listbox-wp8) but this couldn't help.

Here what I am doing in user control

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" >
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Image Source="Images/download.png" Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"/>
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="prg" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Grid>
```

and code behind for user control

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Text",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(SuraWithProgressBar),
    new PropertyMetadata(null));

public string Text
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
  set { SetValue(TextProperty, value);}
}
```

The usage

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsbQuranData" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel>
<local:SuraWithProgressBar Text="{Binding SuraTName, ElementName=SuraWithProgressBar}"></local:SuraWithProgressBar>
<Line X1="0" X2="480" Y1="0" Y2="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black" />
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and code behind for usage

```
lsbQuranData.ItemsSource = App.Chapter;
```

Let me mention that "App.Chapter" contain "SuraTName" which is binded to Text property of user control. The user control is added in list box, but the text is not displayed.

Comment: When you add a converter, your value is not null?

Comment: sorry I didn't get it, I have not used Converter. (there are 114 items displayed and binding value is never null)

Comment: If you write anything instead of your binding. For exemple "toto"? What  is append?

Comment: nothing appears (its empty), when I edited the Text Property in user control with the "TextBlock.Text = value;" I just appended this statement there it showed the text "toto", but not the binding.

Comment: Ok i think i found, you search SuratName property in the element SuraWithProgressBar, it's wrong. Delete this property, juste write text="{binding SuratName}".

Comment: this doesn't help either.

Comment: Add converter check value, this will help us to understand your problèm

Comment: Thanks, In converter I can see the value while debugging.

Comment: And the value is good? now put a breakpoint in setproperty in your usercontrol

Comment: The value is there, while debugging it is not coming in these two "TextProperty" and "Text".

Comment: I find the solution. check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I came up with following solution.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Text",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(SuraWithProgressBar),
    new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

I changed the "Text" to "SuraTName" and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Converter is a good thing for debug binding issue =>

```
 public sealed class DebugConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, In converter I can see the value while debugging. it returns the value but nothing is displayed in textblock.